# Trim doesn't seem to work PHP

Tags: php

I'm a fan of the function `trim` in PHP. However, I think I've run into a weird snag. I have the string named keys that contains: "mavrick, ball,  bouncing, food,  easy mac, " and execute this function

```
// note the double space before "bouncing"
$keys = "mavrick, ball,  bouncing, food,  easy mac, ";
$theKeywords = explode(", ", $keys);
foreach($theKeywords as $key){
  $key = trim($key);
}
echo $theKeywords[2];
```

However here, the output is " bouncing"  not "bouncing". Isn't `trim` the right function to use here?

edit:

My original string has two spaces before "bounce", for some reason it didn't want to show up.
And I tried referencing it with foreach($theKeywords as &$key) but it threw an error.

Comment: Well, if you use trim() why you explode with ", " instead of just "," ?

Comment: `code`Parse error: parse error, unexpected '&', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in chooseCats.php on line 40`code`

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you work with a copy and not the original value. Use references instead:

```
$theKeywords = explode(", ", $keys);
foreach($theKeywords as &$key){
  $key = trim($key);
}
echo $theKeywords[2];
```

Comment: Also don't forget to `unset($key)` after the loop to avoid problems when using the same variable later.

Comment: @Maerlyn thanks for that tip I did not know that yet. I expected that $key would just be valid in that scope.

Comment: I get a 'Parse error: parse error, unexpected '&', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$' in chooseCats.php on line 40`code' error when I do that though...

Comment: @rekire it would be valid, but it'd still hold a reference to the last item in your array

Comment: @rekire like JavaScript, PHP only has a global and function scope for variables. There is no block level scope in PHP. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: But no matter what method, all of these result in the same " bouncing". It gets rid of one space but not two.

Comment: You shouldn't really use references in foreach, you should instead use something like $theKeywords[$key] = ... read the php doc to see why.

Comment: @VBAssassin Please do explain why, that makes your comment so much more useful.

Comment: @user1848437 What exactly do you mean? `trim()` gets rid of *all* [**surrounding "whitespace"**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: @phant0m it's just a comment, do what the comment says and go to the php docs and you will see this, "Reference of a $value and the last array element remain even after the foreach loop." and since he used a reference in the foreach - that applies. Stop being so anal. But in that case, how does YOUR comment help anyone?

Comment: @VBAssassin There is no need for name calling. The PHP docs are pretty big and not too well organized, so except for you nobody knows for certain what exactly you meant. If you include the important bits in your comment as you now did, there is no room for misunderstandings. Also, you don't get any annoying people to ask you questions you don't like ;) Anyway, that point was already raised by Maerlyn, so I assumed you were referring to something different. Also, the solution you proposed requires you iterate over `array_keys()`, whether that is preferable is a matter of style, not fact.

Comment: @phant0m it just means changing this "&$key){" to "$akey=>$key){" and using $akey on the original array. I'm sure there was another reason to not using references but i can't remember that one :/ not sure if anyone else knows but never mind that. You may be annoying and i'm sure you have started stalking me on here, but i quite like you because of how annoying you are and you fight back which i find amusing :D lol.

Answer (score 3):

You're not re-writing the values in the original array in your loop, you could simplify this to one line, using `array_map`, like so

```
$theKeywords = array_map('trim', explode(',', $keys));
```

Comment: +1 very concise - does no more or no less than what it needs to :)

Answer (score 1):

`$key` gets a copy of the value, not the actual value. To update the actual value, modify it in the array itself (for example, by using a `for` loop):

```
$theKeywords = explode(", ", $keys);
for($i = 0; $i < count($theKeywords); $i++) {
    $theKeywords[$i] = trim($theKeywords[$i]);
}
echo $theKeywords[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using a closure:

```
$keys = "mavrick, ball,  bouncing, food,  easy mac, ";
$theKeywords = explode(", ", $keys);
array_walk($theKeywords, function (&$item, $key) {
    $item = trim($item);
});
print $theKeywords[2];
```

But, it will only work in PHP 5.3+